# Check a data field value in all child components from parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Below is the parent component where I have three child component. I am using vue tabs to display each child component under each tab. The user can navigate to a different tab by clicking on `<v-tab href="# ">`. Each child component has a field called `changes` which is a boolean field and defaulted to false. The issue I am facing here is that, I want to raise an alert message on clicking  whenever any child component has `changes` field is true. How can I check a value from parent in all child component?

```
<template>
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 sm12 lg12>
     <div>
        <v-tabs v-model="current_tab">
          <v-tab href="#information">INFORMATION</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#details">DETAILS</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#services">SERVICES</v-tab>
          <v-tab-item value="#information" id="information">
           <Information />
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item value="#details" id="details">
           <Details />
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item value="#services" id="services">
           <Services />
          </v-tab-item>
         </v-tabs>
       </div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
  import Information from 'views/information/edit.vue';
  import Details from 'views/details/edit.vue';
  import Services from 'views/services/edit.vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      Information,
      Details,
      Services,
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        current_tab: 'information',
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Below is the child component sample where changes field is set to false.

```
<template>
  <div>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>  
  export default {
   data: function () {
    return {
      changes: false
    };
   },
  }
</script>
```

Update 1

child component

```
watch: {
 changes: function(value) {
  if (value) {
     this.$emit('changes-event')
  }        
 }
}
```

parent-component

```
<Information v-on:changes-event="alertMessage"/>

export default {
  methods: {
   alertMessage() {
     console.log("Alert: changes has been mutated.")
   }
  }
};
```

Comment: Why not just use $emit to send am event from the child to the parent when the *changes* is updated?

Comment: @crosen9999 not sure how to get that working

Comment: Please  check my answer again, as I'm afraid I made changes midstream.  For example, the doSomething() method should be called alertMessage() so that it matches what is defined in the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the $emit function to send events from the child to the parent when the `change` value is updated.

First, in the child components (Information, Details and Services), you watch for `changes` to mutate and turn TRUE.  When it does, emit an event like so:

```
watch: {
 changes: function(value) {
  if (value) {
     this.$emit('changes-event')
  }        
 }
}
```

(In the above example, 'changes-event' is the name you assign to the custom event.)

Then, in the parent component, you listen for the event just like any other event:

```
      <v-tabs v-model="current_tab">
          <v-tab href="#information">INFORMATION</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#details">DETAILS</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#services">SERVICES</v-tab>
          <v-tab-item value="#information" id="information">
           <Information v-on:changes-event="alertMessage"/>
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item value="#details" id="details">
           <Details v-on:changes-event="alertMessage"/>
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item value="#services" id="services">
           <Services v-on:changes-event="alertMessage"/>
          </v-tab-item>
         </v-tabs>
```

And, then add a method alertMessage to handle the alert:

```
  export default {
    
    methods: {
      alertMessage() {
        console.log("Alert: changes has been mutated.")
      }
    }
  };
```

You can find more information about events here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: I should add a watcher on the change field?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good place to put the call to $emit.

Comment: v-on:change="alertMessage" isnt working. 

I just added a random alertMessage method on the parent component. It is not triggers when I click on any tab.

Comment: Can you please explain this point?
(In the above example, 'changes-event' is the name you assign to the custom event.)

Comment: In the line that reads "this.$emit('changes-event')",  you have emitted an event with the name 'changes-event'.  If the line read "this.$emit('my-event')", then you would have emitted an event named 'my-event'.  The key is that whatever event name you use here has to match the event name that you use in the parent:  So, if the event name is 'changes-event' in the child, then the parent should read "<Information v-on:changes-event="alertMessage"/>

Comment: perfect. I should trigger this event only when changes field is true right?

Comment: Just change "<Information v-on:change="alertMessage"/>" to read "<Information v-on:changes-event="alertMessage"/>".  The idea is that the name of the event in the "$emit" statement must match the name of the event in the "on:" directive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218927/discussion-between-user12763413-and-crosen9999).